# How to Increase counts in database using javascript increment method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, increment

I have field called `ads_counter` in my database, and I need to increase its value each time when this ad is rendered.

I want to implement  increment function of javascript in node rest api when be clicked by users I will get `1` in request I have increase no in database by `1`. for example If I have `ads_counter = 5` and I get req from client side to increase no by `1`. so, how can I increase no. of `ads_counter` in database.  I'm not able to understand from where to start I am using Sequelize with postgres database. please suggest me good method to do this opreation.

Comment: `UPDATE table_name
set ads_counter = ads_counter + 5
WHERE condition` to increment count

Comment: thanks for your reply, I got my answer from here https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7268

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got The answer I have to add below code in my node api I have to get `product_id` from the client side and this api will increase the `ads_counter` by 1.

```
Product.update({ ads_counter: sequelize.literal('ads_counter+ 1') }, { where: { id: req.body.id } });
```

this is the [link](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7268) of git issue from where I got my answer