# How to get upvote, downvote count for a post using sequelize query

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, relational-database

Currently I use below sequelize query to get list of post with reactions association as array of object. Now, To get reactions(Upvote and download) count I used  below Sequelize Query.

```
Post.findAll({
  order: [["updatedAt", "DESC"]],
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
      attributes: ["id", "userName", "firstName", "lastName", "email"],
    },
    Category,
    { model: Comment, include: User },
    {
      model: Reaction,
      attributes: {
        include: [
          [
            Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("Reaction.id")),
            "reactionCount",
          ],
        ],
      },
      where: {
        userId: user.id,
      },
      group: ["Reaction.id"],
    },
  ],
})
```

But it throws below error.
[image]

Below you could find my table relations
[image]

Comment: check out this answer i also faced same problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/64182965/12761193

Comment: i am not using counter field for upvote and downvote.  I update reaction table with status key 0 if user clicks downvote and 1 if user clicks upvote. update working fine. Now, I need only a query to get total upvote and downvote count  based on status.

Comment: at counter you have to put your column name which you want to update on upvote

Comment: Thanks, adding  column solves my issue.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote it :)